# TypeError: _firebaseConfig.default.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am trying to use firebase for my chat application developed using React Native and I am getting following error while pushing records into firebase.

> [TypeError: _firebaseConfig.default.database is not a function. (In '_firebaseConfig.default.database()', '_firebaseConfig.default.database' is undefined)]

I have created a firebase configuration file as below.

firebase-config.js

```
import Firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  appId: '',
};

export default Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Messages.js

```
import Firebase from './firebase-config';

export const sendMessage = async (from, to, message) => {
  try {
    return await Firebase.database()
      .ref('messages/' + from)
      .child(to)
      .set({
        from: from,
        to: to,
        message: message,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const receiveMessage = async (from, to, message) => {
  try {
    return await getDatabase(Firebase)
      .ref('messages/' + to)
      .child(from)
      .push({
        from: from,
        to: to,
        message: message,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not importing the Realtime Database SDK anywhere, so when you try to then access `firebase.database()` you get an error saying that it can't be found.

To fix this, import the Realtime Database SDK after you `import Firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'`.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/database';
...
```

I recommend also checking out the example in the upgrade guide on [updating imports to v9 compat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat).

Comment: Thanks a lot.   After adding  
```
import 'firebase/compat/database';

```
worked for me

Comment: Good to hear @kumarsanket.  ---- Don't forget to accept the answer once the system allows that! :)

Comment: Hello Frank , The above solution is working fine for android but in case of ios I am getting the same error. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: There should be no difference between iOS and Android handling here, but it's hard to say more with a repro. I'd recommend opening a new question with sufficient [debugging details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow others to help you troubleshoot too.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your valuable inputs.